# Where Can I Find The SSIS Log/SSIS Error Log For DTSX Packages That Are Packaged Deployed?

Tags: logging, ssis

Where can I look for the SSIS Log for those packages that are deployed through Package deployment and not Project Deployment? The packages themselves are deployed on a shared drive not on SQL Server.

I am trying to troubleshoot the error

> Source: "Microsoft Access Database Engine" Hresult: 0x80004005 Description: "External table is not in the expected format.".'

This occurs occasionally on different packages that are run through a SQL Agent job.

Answer (score 0):

Packages deployed to the file system are use the Legacy/Package deployment model.

Unless someone explicitly added logging during development, you won't have an explicit log.

Probably.

The SSIS package itself can log events and activities but you might be able to catch errors if you explicitly ask for that to be logged when the package runs.  Assuming you use [dtexec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/packages/dtexec-utility?view=sql-server-ver16) either through an explicit command line call or invoke it via the SQL Agent SSIS job subsystem, you can specify the `/REP`orting level of `E`rrors, `W`arning, and `I`nformation which I always advocated clients use. Warnings are just errors waiting to grow up. Information events catch things like fouled up configuration files and Foreach File enumerators that lack file system permissions to list the files/access the folder. Errors are well errors.

What you do with the output from dtexec is up to you. SQL Agent job you can specify the job step retain the output. If you're running it through a command line call, you can redirect output to a file with a redirect operator `>`

```
dtexec.exe /f \\server\share\mypackage.dtsx /REP EIW > D:\logs\mypackage_2023-12-30.txt
```

That will run the package located on a file share and write the results to the D drive under a file with today's date.

A comment asks

> Do you think turning on logging might help to troubleshoot?

A challenge with legacy packages is that you can't enable native logging without modifying the package. I have seen cases, early on at least, where editing a package to do something trivial like enabling logging resulted in a package never raising the error I went in to troubleshoot. Maybe it was an old package and newer tooling fixed something that wasn't set right.

Modifying the job/caller of a package is much less likely to break as it won't change the internals. It certainly won't hurt and likely can only provide insight into what is happening in the package execution.

The error "External table is not in the expected format" doesn't feel like a problem with the package per se. During development, SSIS creates a tight mapping between source and destination schemas. Normally, when a source/destination changes, SSIS will error out with VS_NEEDSNEWMETADATA error which is what your error smells like but not. Especially if it's intermittent. I'm not an Access aficionado but maybe someone else is in the database at the time SSIS attempts to query it and that is causing the table to be a funky state/format. Or there's another package running that isn't finished when it would normally be done. A host of possibilities really but without a minimal reproducible problem definition, we'd be playing the worst game of "Go Fish"

Comment: Thanks!  I am still trying to troublehsoot the error - 'Source: "Microsoft Access Database Engine"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "External table is not in the expected format.".' that occurs occassionally on different packages that are run through an Agent job.  Do you think turning on logging might help to troubleshoot? I am just trying to find out what the first error is.

Comment: Took a stab at addressing your comment/question refinement. LMK if that helps any

Comment: Thanks!  I think the main issue is that the package/s are orginally created and the Excel file exists  in order to create the Excel destination connector and it runs ok. However, in the agent job, step one deletes the Excel file/s, and then each SSIS package creates a new excel file and pushes that data to it.  Maybe somedays, the SSIS package is ok, other days it is not.  The alternative is to not drop those Excels, but I am not sure how to just delete a tab out of the Excel file and push data into that one tab, which is this case is called 'Sheet1'.  Thanks!